# How to apply a ParamConverter to a specific controler only?

Tags: php, symfony, autowired

I am working on migrating an existing `Symfony 2.8` project to `Symfony 3.4`. Beside the Symfony version also the `sensio/framework-extra-bundle` was updated from `3.0.19` to `5.2.4`.

The project uses separat `ParamConverter` for two different controllers. While this worked fine in in the `Symfony 2.8` project, it fails in the `Symfony 3.4` project. It seems that now both converters are applied to both controllers.

```
// The first controller uses a standard `fos_rest.request_body` converter
class ControllerA extends FOSRestController {
    /**
     * @FOSRest\View()
     * @ParamConverter("chartOptions", converter="fos_rest.request_body")
     */
    public function chartDataAction(Request $request, ChartOptions $chartOptions) {
        ...
    }
}

class ChartOptions {
    public $date;
    public $name;
    public $title;
}


// The second controller uses a FOS\RestBundle\Request\RequestBodyParamConverter subclass as converter
class ControllerB extends FOSRestController {
    /**
     * @FOSRest\View()
     * @ParamConverter("dataBag", converter="custom_converter")
     */
    public function dataAction(Request $request, DataBag $dataBag) {
        ...
    }
}

class CustomConverter extend RequestBodyParamConverter {
    ...

    public function apply(Request $request, ParamConverter $configuration) { ... }
}


// services.yml
...
AppBundle\Util\CustomConverter:
    autowire: true
    tags:
        - { name: request.param_converter, converter: custom_converter }
    arguments:         
        $serializer: '@fos_rest.serializer'
        $validator: '@?fos_rest.validator'
```

I would assume that each of these two converters is only applied when the corresponding controller is called. This worked in `Symfony 2.8` but is not the case in `Symfony 3.4`.

When I open a page which calls `chartDataAction()` using an `Ajax` call an exception is thrown `CustomConverter.apply(...)` The problem is, that the `apply()` method is not meant to handle the content of this call.

Of course I could catch/handle the exception but this would not solve the overall problem: **Why is `CustomConverter` used at all on this call?**

After some research I tried to solve the problem by setting `auto_convert` to `false` within the `config.yml` :

```
# app/config/config.yml
sensio_framework_extra:
    request:
        converters: true
        auto_convert: false
```

While this seems to solve the problem with the `CustomConverter` I now get another exception:

> Uncaught PHP Exception RuntimeException: "Converter
>   'fos_rest.request_body' does not support conversion of parameter
>   'chartOptions'

**So, what might be the cause of the problem? How to apply the converters only to the specific controllers?**

**EDIT:**

After re-reading the [Symfony docs](https://symfony.com/doc/master/bundles/SensioFrameworkExtraBundle/annotations/converters.html) I am even more confuses by this behaviour:

> To detect which converter is run on a parameter the following process
>   is run:
>
> If an explicit converter choice was made with @ParamConverter(converter="name") the converter with the given name is
>   chosen. Otherwise all registered parameter converters are iterated by priority.

Both controller do specify the converter using `@ParamConverter(converter="name")`. So why is `custom_converter` applied to `chartDataAction()` instead of `fos_rest.request_body`. ?